# PHP 2 different project but shows only 1

Tags: javascript, php, web

I have 2 php projects but it only show 1 project. For example I have Localhost:8080\app which is the main app and Localhost:8080\app_dev for the development or the replicate but it has different HTTP content.

Whenever i browse the Localhost:8080\app_dev it shows the main app and Localhost:8080\app works fine.

Comment: may be htaccess or any other kind of redirection issue. The topic is too broad to conclude anything.

Comment: does your project is in symfony?

Comment: @david It was located at htdocs and i was using xampp as apache.

Comment: probably you have some kind of redirection, check .htaccess or wrong redirection in your app_dev

Comment: which framework you are using? May be your app_dev's configuration is point to app as its copied from app, you need to change the directory path for app_dev